# Webdav PROPFIND, no response with Curl or Postman

Tags: curl, postman, webdav

I have a webdav server running on local network and I'm able to get responses with other requests, but PROPFIND leaves both Curl and Postman hanging without returning anything, though I see the response being successful (207 Multi-Status) with Wireshark. I'm suspecting something related to network adapter or chunked encoding, but could really use your help on this! Working with Mac/Catalina and the following line:

```
curl --location --request PROPFIND 'http://192.168.1.102/DATALOG' \
--header 'Content-Type: text/xml' \
--header 'Depth:  1' \
--header 'Accept:  */*' \
--data-raw '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><D:propfind xmlns:D="DAV:"><D:prop><D:getlastmodified/><D:getcontentlength/><D:creationdate/><D:resourcetype/></D:prop></D:propfind>'
```

EDIT:
Here's an example response, to me it seems all the cr/lfs are in place but I do get a complaint of missing cr in httpolice.

```
00000000  48 54 54 50 2f 31 2e 31  20 32 30 37 20 4d 75 6c   HTTP/1.1  207 Mul
00000010  74 69 2d 53 74 61 74 75  73 0d 0a 53 65 72 76 65   ti-Statu s..Serve
00000020  72 3a 20 58 63 65 72 65  62 65 6c 6c 75 6d 2f 31   r: Xcere bellum/1
00000030  2e 30 0d 0a 43 6f 6e 6e  65 63 74 69 6f 6e 3a 20   .0..Conn ection: 
00000040  63 6c 6f 73 65 0d 0a 43  6f 6e 74 65 6e 74 2d 54   close..C ontent-T
00000050  79 70 65 3a 20 74 65 78  74 2f 78 6d 6c 0d 0a 4c   ype: tex t/xml..L
00000060  6f 63 61 74 69 6f 6e 3a  20 68 74 74 70 3a 2f 2f   ocation:  http://
00000070  31 39 32 2e 31 36 38 2e  31 2e 31 30 32 2f 44 43   192.168. 1.102/DC
00000080  49 4d 2f 0d 0a 54 72 61  6e 73 66 65 72 2d 45 6e   IM/..Tra nsfer-En
00000090  63 6f 64 69 6e 67 3a 20  63 68 75 6e 6b 65 64 0d   coding:  chunked.
000000A0  0a 0d 0a                                           ...
000000A3  3c 3f 78 6d 6c 20 76 65  72 73 69 6f 6e 3d 27 31   <?xml ve rsion='1
000000B3  2e 30 27 20 65 6e 63 6f  64 69 6e 67 3d 27 75 74   .0' enco ding='ut
000000C3  66 2d 38 27 3f 3e 3c 44  3a 6d 75 6c 74 69 73 74   f-8'?><D :multist
000000D3  61 74 75 73 20 78 6d 6c  6e 73 3a 62 3d 27 75 72   atus xml ns:b='ur
000000E3  6e 3a 75 75 69 64 3a 63  32 66 34 31 30 31 30 2d   n:uuid:c 2f41010-
000000F3  36 35 62 33 2d 31 31 64  31 2d 61 32 39 66 2d 30   65b3-11d 1-a29f-0
00000103  30 61 61 30 30 63 31 34  38 38 32 2f 27 20 78 6d   0aa00c14 882/' xm
00000113  6c 6e 73 3a 63 3d 27 78  6d 6c 3a 27 20 78 6d 6c   lns:c='x ml:' xml
00000123  6e 73 3a 44 3d 27 44 41  56 3a 27 3e 3c 44 3a 72   ns:D='DA V:'><D:r
00000133  65 73 70 6f 6e 73 65 3e  3c 44 3a 68 72 65 66 3e   esponse> <D:href>
00000143  68 74 74 70 3a 2f 2f 31  39 32 2e 31 36 38 2e 31   http://1 92.168.1
00000153  2e 31 30 32 2f 44 43 49  4d 2f 3c 2f 44 3a 68 72   .102/DCI M/</D:hr
00000163  65 66 3e 3c 44 3a 70 72  6f 70 73 74 61 74 3e 3c   ef><D:pr opstat><
00000173  44 3a 70 72 6f 70 3e 3c  44 3a 72 65 73 6f 75 72   D:prop>< D:resour
00000183  63 65 74 79 70 65 3e 3c  44 3a 63 6f 6c 6c 65 63   cetype>< D:collec
00000193  74 69 6f 6e 2f 3e 3c 2f  44 3a 72 65 73 6f 75 72   tion/></ D:resour
000001A3  63 65 74 79 70 65 3e 3c  44 3a 67 65 74 63 6f 6e   cetype>< D:getcon
000001B3  74 65 6e 74 6c 65 6e 67  74 68 3e 30 3c 2f 44 3a   tentleng th>0</D:
000001C3  67 65 74 63 6f 6e 74 65  6e 74 6c 65 6e 67 74 68   getconte ntlength
000001D3  3e 3c 44 3a 69 73 72 65  61 64 6f 6e 6c 79 3e 30   ><D:isre adonly>0
000001E3  3c 2f 44 3a 69 73 72 65  61 64 6f 6e 6c 79 3e 3c   </D:isre adonly><
000001F3  2f 44 3a 70 72 6f 70 3e  3c 44 3a 73 74 61 74 75   /D:prop> <D:statu
00000203  73 3e 48 54 54 50 2f 31  2e 31 20 32 30 30 20 4f   s>HTTP/1 .1 200 O
00000213  4b 3c 2f 44 3a 73 74 61  74 75 73 3e 3c 2f 44 3a   K</D:sta tus></D:
00000223  70 72 6f 70 73 74 61 74  3e 3c 44 3a 70 72 6f 70   propstat ><D:prop
00000233  73 74 61 74 3e 3c 44 3a  70 72 6f 70 3e 3c 44 3a   stat><D: prop><D:
00000243  63 72 65 61 74 69 6f 6e  64 61 74 65 2f 3e 3c 44   creation date/><D
00000253  3a 67 65 74 6c 61 73 74  6d 6f 64 69 66 69 65 64   :getlast modified
00000263  2f 3e 3c 2f 44 3a 70 72  6f 70 3e 3c 44 3a 73 74   /></D:pr op><D:st
00000273  61 74 75 73 3e 48 54 54  50 2f 31 2e 31 20 34 30   atus>HTT P/1.1 40
00000283  34 20 4e 6f 74 20 46 6f  75 6e 64 3c 2f 44 3a 73   4 Not Fo und</D:s
00000293  74 61 74 75 73 3e 3c 2f  44 3a 70 72 6f 70 73 74   tatus></ D:propst
000002A3  61 74 3e 3c 2f 44 3a 72  65 73 70 6f 6e 73 65 3e   at></D:r esponse>
000002B3  3c 44 3a 72 65 73 70 6f  6e 73 65 3e 3c 44 3a 68   <D:respo nse><D:h
000002C3  72 65 66 3e 68 74 74 70  3a 2f 2f 31 39 32 2e 31   ref>http ://192.1
000002D3  36 38 2e 31 2e 31 30 32  2f 44 43 49 4d 2f 31 30   68.1.102 /DCIM/10
000002E3  30 5f 5f 54 53 42 2f 3c  2f 44 3a 68 72 65 66 3e   0__TSB/< /D:href>
000002F3  3c 44 3a 70 72 6f 70 73  74 61 74 3e 3c 44 3a 70   <D:props tat><D:p
00000303  72 6f 70 3e 3c 44 3a 72  65 73 6f 75 72 63 65 74   rop><D:r esourcet
00000313  79 70 65 3e 3c 44 3a 63  6f 6c 6c 65 63 74 69 6f   ype><D:c ollectio
00000323  6e 2f 3e 3c 2f 44 3a 72  65 73 6f 75 72 63 65 74   n/></D:r esourcet
00000333  79 70 65 3e 3c 44 3a 67  65 74 63 6f 6e 74 65 6e   ype><D:g etconten
00000343  74 6c 65 6e 67 74 68 3e  30 3c 2f 44 3a 67 65 74   tlength> 0</D:get
00000353  63 6f 6e 74 65 6e 74 6c  65 6e 67 74 68 3e 3c 44   contentl ength><D
00000363  3a 69 73 72 65 61 64 6f  6e 6c 79 3e 30 3c 2f 44   :isreado nly>0</D
00000373  3a 69 73 72 65 61 64 6f  6e 6c 79 3e 3c 2f 44 3a   :isreado nly></D:
00000383  70 72 6f 70 3e 3c 44 3a  73 74 61 74 75 73 3e 48   prop><D: status>H
00000393  54 54 50 2f 31 2e 31 20  32 30 30 20 4f 4b 3c 2f   TTP/1.1  200 OK</
000003A3  44 3a 73 74 61 74 75 73  3e 3c 2f 44 3a 70 72 6f   D:status ></D:pro
000003B3  70 73 74 61 74 3e 3c 44  3a 70 72 6f 70 73 74 61   pstat><D :propsta
000003C3  74 3e 3c 44 3a 70 72 6f  70 3e 3c 44 3a 63 72 65   t><D:pro p><D:cre
000003D3  61 74 69 6f 6e 64 61 74  65 2f 3e 3c 44 3a 67 65   ationdat e/><D:ge
000003E3  74 6c 61 73 74 6d 6f 64  69 66 69 65 64 2f 3e 3c   tlastmod ified/><
000003F3  2f 44 3a 70 72 6f 70 3e  3c 44 3a 73 74 61 74 75   /D:prop> <D:statu
00000403  73 3e 48 54 54 50 2f 31  2e 31 20 34 30 34 20 4e   s>HTTP/1 .1 404 N
00000413  6f 74 20 46 6f 75 6e 64  3c 2f 44 3a 73 74 61 74   ot Found </D:stat
00000423  75 73 3e 3c 2f 44 3a 70  72 6f 70 73 74 61 74 3e   us></D:p ropstat>
00000433  3c 2f 44 3a 72 65 73 70  6f 6e 73 65 3e 3c 2f 44   </D:resp onse></D
00000443  3a 6d 75 6c 74 69 73 74  61 74 75 73 3e            :multist atus>
```

Comment: A hanging response suggests that this is a server bug. If there was a mistake in your request I would simply expect an error to be returned.

Comment: I still do see the response with Wireshark as 207, that's why I'm leaning more towards client end.

Answer (score 0):

(this isn't an answer, it's a debugging request, but it's too long to be a comment)

my best guess: your WebDAV server isn't properly following the HTTP protocol's \r\n\r\n delimiter scheme (possibly a server bug?) you (or at least I) can debug this by creating the request with netcat and dumping the response to a file and reading the file in a hex editor, in order to get the server's raw response to a file, try:

> printf UFJPUEZJTkQgL0RBVEFMT0cgSFRUUC8xLjENCkhvc3Q6IDE5Mi4xNjguMS4xMDINClVzZXItQWdlbnQ6IGN1cmwvNy43MS4xDQpDb250ZW50LVR5cGU6IHRleHQveG1sDQpEZXB0aDogIDENCkFjY2VwdDogICovKg0KQ29udGVudC1MZW5ndGg6IDE3MA0KDQo8P3htbCB2ZXJzaW9uPSIxLjAiIGVuY29kaW5nPSJ1dGYtOCI/PjxEOnByb3BmaW5kIHhtbG5zOkQ9IkRBVjoiPjxEOnByb3A+PEQ6Z2V0bGFzdG1vZGlmaWVkLz48RDpnZXRjb250ZW50bGVuZ3RoLz48RDpjcmVhdGlvbmRhdGUvPjxEOnJlc291cmNldHlwZS8+PC9EOnByb3A+PC9EOnByb3BmaW5kPg== | base64 -d | nc 192.168.1.102 80 > server_response.bin

(PS, this is written in a linux-style that won't work on standard Windows, if you don't have a Linux terminal on your windows, you can get a linux-y terminal from [Cygwin](https://cygwin.org/) or if you're on Windows 10, you can use WSL, the above example was tested on Cygwin, but should work in any standard Linux terminal)

since i guess the socket isn't closed automatically (possibly due to a "connection: keep-alive"-scheme on the server?), let it run for at least 10 seconds before terminating netcat, if it doesn't terminate by itself,

now inspect server_response.bin **in a hex editor** (my personal favorite hex editor is [HxD Hex Editor](https://mh-nexus.de/en/hxd/) )

and check the server_response.bin , does the response contain a `Content-Length` header? does the declared Content-Length match the actual content length? was the response's headers actually separated by the response's body with the `0D 0A 0D 0A` bytes?

if the answer to any of those questions is `no`, then it's probably a bug in the WebDAV server you're using, and could explain curl hanging (waiting for the response body perhaps?) but maybe upload your server_response.bin and let us at StackOverflow have a look? (it's easy to miss something, especially if you don't have experience with inspecting data at the binary/hex level)

Comment: server_response.bin remains empty, and yet again I can catch it in WS as follows. Content-Length doesn't exist as it's chunked encoding. Also the chunks seem to have correct length and termination (0d0a) HTTP/1.1 207 Multi-Status\r\n
        Response Version: HTTP/1.1
        Status Code: 207
        Response Phrase: Multi-Status
    Server: Xcerebellum/1.0\r\n
    Connection: close\r\n
    Content-Type: text/xml\r\n
    Location: http://192.168.1.102/DATALOG/\r\n
    Transfer-Encoding: chunked\r\n
    \r\n
    HTTP chunked response

Comment: @tkby wow that's... bizarre; maybe you're right about the network adapter after all.. are you running some kind of 3rdparty firewall or something that could explain this? also.. maybe try ```netsh winsock reset``` , but that's.. super weird

Comment: I think the issue is bit deeper and the ip packet is dropped on the way, maybe due to invalid tcp checksum. Not sure if its in my hands to solve, probably need to do some magic hacking to get the dir. It’s still odd that Mac finder can mount the drive using the same request.

Comment: @tkby .. i would suspect a firewall or a virus until you get the same result from a different system on the same network. can you test it on another system altogether?